# Converting CrystalEnterprise.FavoritesFolder to CrystalEnterprise.Folder using SAP BO SDK

Tags: c#, .net, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Hi I m trying to copy a CrystalEnterprise.FavoritesFolder to a backup folder but I am not able to create a backup as it is throwing me and error as follows:

> Desktop plugin object CrystalEnterprise.FavoritesFolder is not creatable.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can't create a Favorites folder manually.  Just create a normal (public) folder, and copy the contents of the Favorites folder into it.